# My tab navigation header button doesnt working. How can I fix it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, button, navigation

I'm trying to learn react native and I have a problem. Here I use tab navigation and I want to add an image in my headers right side and when the users touch that image I want use navigator, but it doesn't work.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { View, StyleSheet, Image, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs'
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';


const TabNavigation = ({ navigation }) => {

    return (
    enter code here

 <Tab.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={HomeScreen}
          options={{
            headerTitle: () => (<Image source={require('../Images/Floody.png')} />),
            headerStyle: {
              height: 100
            },
            headerTitleAlign: 'center',
            headerRight: () => (
              <TouchableOpacity>
                <Image source={require('../Images/profile.jpg')} />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            ),
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => focused ? <HomeImageColorfull /> : <HomeImageBlack />
          }} />
```

Answer (score 0):

The `navigation` object is passed by the navigation framework to the `options` of the screen. Hence, you can implement a `onPress` function for your `TouchableOpacity` of your `headerRight` component and use the `navigation` object from the options.

```js
<Tab.Screen
   name="Home"
   component={HomeScreen}
   options={({navigation}) => ({
            headerTitle: () => (<Image source={require('../Images/Floody.png')} />),
            headerStyle: {
              height: 100
            },
            headerTitleAlign: 'center',
            headerRight: () => (
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("SomeScreenToNavigateTo")}>
                <Image source={require('../Images/profile.jpg')} />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            ),
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => focused ? <HomeImageColorfull /> : <HomeImageBlack />
          })} />
```

Comment: i tried that you suggested but it doesnt work. İt cant be render that page which i wanna navigate to .

Comment: I'm not sure what you are referring to. Is the screen defined in the navigator? Is there an error message? What exactly is happening?

Comment: i am using tab navigator and i have to use stack navigator in tab bar header. is that possible ?

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean. You can obviously only navigate to screens that are defined in a navigator. The navigation object, as used in my answer, works as intended, but if your navigation logic is wrong then the error is obvious. If your screen is inside a nested stack navigator, then it depends on how you have defined the stack navigator, e.g. ScreenA is located in StackA, then StackA is added to a tab in  Tab.Navigator. This should fix any issue.

Comment: " e.g. ScreenA is located in StackA, then StackA is added to a tab in Tab.Navigator. This should fix any issue"  this is my answer. Thank you and sorry for my bad english :)